# Edit Mysql data through HTML and PHP generated table filled with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a mysql table. I have created a html table and filled it with data from my mysql table using php and sql. I then want to be able to click a checkbox next to each row of data, and click edit, and be able to edit the data all from the webpage.

Code which i used to build the html table and fill it with mysql data:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
 if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
 $r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $table="<table><tr style='background:#cccccc;'>";
 $firstLine="<tr>";
 foreach ($r as $k => $v){
   $table .="<td style='border:1px #ffffff solid;'>".$k."</td>";
   $firstLine .="<td>".$v."</td>";
 }
 $table.="</tr>".$firstLine."</tr>";
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $table.="<tr>";
   foreach($r as $k => $v)
     $table.="<td>".$v."</td>";
   $table.="</tr>";
 }
  $table .="</table>";
 echo $table;
}
```

Can anyone help provide me with any guidance which will help me achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for phpMyAdmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put each piece of data that could be changed into a text input, instead of just as text, with the value attribute what's coming from the db and a name which can identify it. That way, you can check the box next to the text input and change it. when the data is sent to the server, anytime a checkbox is checked, that's a row that will change in the db.

Answer (score -1):

To use your code

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $table.="<tr>";
    foreach($r as $k => $v) {
        $table.="<td>".$v."</td>";
    } //Dont ever leave this undone, someday you will be very upset
    $table.="<td><span id='{$r["uid"]}'class='uiButtonDelete'></span></td></tr>";
}
```

Now use jQuery to perform the delete.

```
$(function() {
    $(".uiButtonDelete").click(function() {    
        $.post(myDeleteScript, {id: $(this).attr("id")})
        $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut(200)
    })
})
```

Comment: @downvoter, please explain?  I just showed deleting script (obviously as dumb as possible with the SOEditor).  Its easily expandable to make a page for editing, or even inline editing (using the exact same method)... Please tell me what i have done wrong, not just downvote.  If what i am doing is wrong, i would love to take this opportunity to learn!